# Why is my if statement not stopping?

Tags: c#, if-statement, file-extension

I am still new to C# and stuck on this problem.

I am trying to read a file and get the file extension and if the file name does not have '.done' at the end to continue. Then in the rest of my code I upload the data to the database and change the file name to '.done'.

*Problem* is that my If statement that looks at the file is returning true and uploading all the files again instead of just the ones that need to be uploaded. I have tried many ways and none seem to work.

```
DirectoryInfo DirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(sFolder);

FileInfo[] fileEntries = DirInfo.GetFiles("*.*", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

            foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in fileEntries)
            {
                if (fileInfo.Extension != ".done")
                    continue;

                // More code
             }
```

I have tried this also by get all the files. It still loops and uploads all the files again even the ones that have '.done'.

```
DirectoryInfo DirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(sFolder);

FileInfo[] fileEntries = DirInfo.GetFiles();

            foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in fileEntries)
            {
                if (fileInfo.Name != ".done")
                    continue;

                // More code
             }
```

This code works, but I need to change it because file extensions change.

```
DirectoryInfo DirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(sFolder);

FileInfo[] fileEntries = DirInfo.GetFiles("*.ivc", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

            foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in fileEntries)
            {
                if (fileInfo.Name == ".ivc")
                    continue;

                // More code
             }
```

Anything will be of help.

Thanks

Comment: Take a debugger and see why `fileInfo.Extension` is not equal to `".done"`.

Comment: What do you mean by "the file extensions change"?

Comment: sometimes it is .ivc or .G1a or .001. I want to make it where it uploads all files not just .ivc and upload all the files without hard coding each file extension because they change sometimes.

Answer (score 1):

Don't you have your boolean conditional backwards?  You want to to do the rest of your code if the extension IS NOT .done, and go to the next iteration of the loop if IT IS .done, right?  The continue keyword is taking you to the next iteration when the extension is not .done!

```
foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in fileEntries)
{
    if (fileInfo.Name == ".done")
        continue;

    // More code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the 'best coding' practice of using positive thinking when possible (this advice can also be applied to life), because they are generally easier to read. Instead of using a "not equal" condition, use an "is equal" condition, like so:

```
        // just for this example
        var folder = Environment.CurrentDirectory;

        var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(folder);

        // type of files to retrieve
        // @ is for 'string literal' (see link below)
        var extension = @".ivc";  
        // this translates to: "*.ivc"
        var allFiles = @"*" + extension;

        // the extension of files already processed, and hence, skipped
        var skipExtension = @".done";

        var fileEntries = dirInfo.GetFiles(allFiles, System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

        // track number of files processed
        var filesProcessed = 0;

        foreach (var fileInfo in fileEntries)
        {
            // skip files that have already been processed
            if (fileInfo.Extension == skipExtension)
            {
                continue;
            }

            // process new files found in this directory
            filesProcessed++;
        }
```

References:
[String literals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691090%28VS.71%29.aspx%29)

Comment: Thanks Gustavo Mori, I will give this a try.

Comment: @TheRealDK: reviewed the code to separate files that you want to retrieve and the control file used to break from the loop

Comment: @Gustavo-Mori: This is a command prompt program that is always running and checking if there is files in the folder without .done that need to be updated. Also, the file extensions change and I don't want to hard code every time there is maybe one .001 or any other extension. Is that what @"*" takes care of? If I am confusing you sorry.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong: you're trying to skip files that you've already processed (marked with extension "done").

Answer (score 0):

Why not ask for only the files that have the extension you're looking for?

```
DirectoryInfo DirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(sFolder);

FileInfo[] fileEntries = DirInfo.GetFiles("*.done", System.IO.SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

foreach (FileInfo fileInfo in fileEntries)
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: I don't want to process files with .done, I want to process the other ones, and i don't know what all the extensions will be that need to be processed.

Comment: Ah. In that case, it sounds like you're misinterpreting `continue`.  Continue skips the rest of the loop's body and goes on to the next iteration. Instead, what others suggest is right - use continue to skip all processing when the file's extension is equal to ".done".  Or better yet, your code will be more readable if you just drop the continue and enclose the work in the if-block:  `if (FileInfo.Extension != ".done") { //process file }`